# How to sort directories array by creatin time from first to last?

Tags: c#, winforms

so when the string items are adding to the combobox1 it will be ordered in the combobox from the first created directory(old one) at the top first item and the last item at the bottom will be the newest created.

```
private void GetSessionsFolders()
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();

    string rootFolder = lightningsDirectoryTextBox.Text;
    string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(rootFolder);

    sessionDirectories = subDirectories
        .Where(dir =>
        {
            int index = dir.IndexOf("Session_");
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                string sessionFolder = dir.Substring(index + 8);

                string[] subFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
                if (subFolders.Any(subDir => subDir.Contains("Lightning") && Directory.GetFiles(subDir).Length > 0))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sessionFolder);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        })
        .ToList();

    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

This is how I'm creating the Session directories and add them to the comboBox1 in the constructor:

```
string folder = String.Format(@"Session_{0:dddd dd.MM.yyyy} At {0:HH.mm tt}", DateTime.Now);
string folderDateTime = Path.Combine(lightningsDirectoryTextBox.Text, folder);
// Session_
int index = folder.IndexOf("Session_");
string sessionFolder = folder.Substring(index + 8);
comboBox1.Items.Add(sessionFolder);
Directory.CreateDirectory(folderDateTime);
```

The result is like this:

[image: combobox after adding the sessions]

and now I want in both places in the constructor and in the folder GetSessionsFolders to add the Sessions to the comboBox1 in reverse order. so the Session 12.09.2023 At 19:44 will be the first item at the top and the last item will be the newest one 28.09.2023 At 16:12 pm

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question itself. The title should be written as a summary only AFTER the question is complete.

Comment: Use `DirectoryInfo`, which has a property for the creation time that you can sort on.

Comment: (Unrelated to ordering:) You know you can use an overload that takes a search pattern, right? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `DirectoryInfo` instance, you can achieve it like the below :

```
...Select(r=> new DirectoryInfo(r))
     .OrderBy(r=> r.CreationTime)
     .Select(r=> r.FullName).ToList();
```